# Media query not working in css file

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to use media query to make width of divs 100% for smaller screen. Yet, media query does not seem to work on my css file. Part of the code of my css file is as follows:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

However, no change in background-color can be seen. When I put media query on html file, it seems to work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" <!-- media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"  -->type="text/css" href="dec.css">
```

But when I put the code on css file, it just does not work. I am using IE 11 for test. Could anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: try to use : @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

Comment: I tried it before. It's the same. Nothing happens

Comment: are you using bootstrap or other framework?

Comment: just html and css. I think my css file causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you check on another browser, is working?

If yes:
Try change @media all ...  to @media screen in CSS.

If not:
check path to CSS file. Try simple CSS file only with @media...
maybe you have error in CSS (in part not showing us).

Try add !important after color name.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're right. My CSS file causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the value you put in `min-width` and `max-width` are the same (500px) which will cause one rule to always override another if you are testing on a screen with exactly width of 500px.

Try something like:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 501px) {
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```